# Plot a fitted Sarima model in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to evaluate fitting and forecasting of a SARIMA model I produced with R but, once I try to plot the fitted model together with the original series I receive an error message from R. I don't understand why.

Here follows the code

```
fit4<-Arima(fatturati, order=c(1,0,0), seasonal=c(1,1,0))
fit4
Series: fatturati 
ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,1,0)[12]                    

Coefficients:
         ar1     sar1
      0.4749  -0.6135
s.e.  0.1602   0.1556

sigma^2 estimated as 4.773e+10:  log likelihood=-454.47
AIC=914.94   AICc=915.76   BIC=919.43
tsdisplay(residuals(fit4))
Box.test(residuals(fit4), lag=16, fitdf=4, type="Ljung")

    Box-Ljung test

data:  residuals(fit4)
X-squared = 10.15, df = 12, p-value = 0.6028
plot(fit4$x,col="red")
lines(fitted(fit4),col="blue")
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : cannot assign 'tsp' to zero-length vector
```

How can I manage that?

*****UPDATE******
All packages are updated.
Everything seems to be just fine but as soon as I try to plot the fitted data I receive the same error. 
here follows the code

```
fatturati<-read.ts("F:/dati.csv", header=TRUE, start=2013, frequency=12)
ft=fatturati
ft
         Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug         Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2013  397677  642630 1259336 1220071 1883674 1444910  783430  422713     1037768 1046658 1210702  658286
2014  482081  822558 1179159  848265 1235270 1219770  461692  452579     1076500  770226  646424  872482
2015  705441  863377 1104483  944880 1379004 1230724  922313  225545     1064701  721959  728487  738779
2016  586530  939034 1632165 1337850 1697783 1290279  462190  520914     1296145                        
class(ft)
[1] "ts"
arima_fatturati<-Arima(fatturati, order=c(1,0,0), seasonal=c(1,0,0))
arima_fatturati
Series: fatturati 
ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,0,0)[12] with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1    sar1  intercept
      0.3405  0.7370   977132.9
s.e.  0.1408  0.0973   133573.8

sigma^2 estimated as 6.497e+10:  log likelihood=-627.25
AIC=1262.5   AICc=1263.5   BIC=1269.72
plot(arima_fatturati$x, col="red")
lines(fitted.Arima(arima_fatturati), col="blue")
Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : cannot assign 'tsp' to zero-length vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no issues with the following code using a dataset included in the `forecast` package:

```
library(forecast)
arima_wind = Arima(y = wineind, order = c(1, 0, 1), seasonal = c(1, 1, 0))
plot(arima_wind$x)
lines(fitted.Arima(arima_wind), col = "blue")
```

Update the version of `forecast` that you have to be sure that it is not a version issue, but my guess is that this has to do with your specific `ts` object. You might want to post the data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly pushed Enter botton and a partial comment was uploaded.

Comment: @Mark_ Please include your data in slightly more usable format, for example, you could upload the CSV to Dropbox or Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `fitted()` to extract the fitted values. You should be able to access them directly with `$fitted` e.g. `fit4$fitted`.